# Specify bean validation group prior to merge/persist?

Tags: jpa, bean-validation, openjpa

How (or can) I specify programmatically which validation group OpenJPA should validate against during a persist or merge operation? Is this option only available via persistence.xml?

I'm drawing a blank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, configuration is only via *persistence.xml*. I guess it would be open for JPA implementations to provide implementation specific ways, but that's not standardized. I am not sure whether OpenJPa offers such a provider specific option, but I don't think so.

Comment: That's what I'm finding, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: It can be configured programmatically before creating the EntityManagerFactory (I'm using Hibernate and Hibernate Validator.)

Answer (score 2):

The groups are configured per entity manager factory. If you obtain your entity manager factory programmatically via `Persistence#createEntityManagerFactory()` you can pass the groups to be validated during lifecycle validation using the properties `javax.persistence.validation.group.{pre-persist|pre-update|pre-remove}` but there is no (standardized) way for specifying the groups on a per-operation basis.